# Can't resolve dependencies of the ChannelService (? make sure the argument ChannelRepository at index [0] is available in the ChannelService context

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

This is module class:

[image]

This is service class:

[image]

Comment: please share code as text and not images

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ChannelService` in an `imports` array somewhere. Providers never belong in the `imports` array. Without more information, we won't be able to help more. [Check the docs on this common error](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error) and how to resolve it